# Optimize Subselect Search query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

In my MYSQL database I have multiple tables like this:

`reference`:

```
------------------------------
| id | title   | subtitle    |
| 1  | Test    | Just a test |
| 2  | Another | Second      |
| 3  | Last    | Third       |
------------------------------
```

`author`:

```
-----------------------------
| id | firstname | lastname |
| 1  | Peter     | Pan      |
| 2  | Foo       | Bar      |
| 3  | Mr.       | Handsome |
| 4  | Steve     | Jobs     |
-----------------------------
```

`keyword`:

```
----------------
| id | keyword |
| 1  | boring  |
| 1  | lame    |
----------------
```

`reference_author_mm`:

```
---------------------------
| uid_local | uid_foreign |
| 1         | 1           |
| 1         | 2           |
| 2         | 1           |
| 2         | 2           |
| 2         | 4           |
| 3         | 1           |
| 3         | 2           |
| 3         | 4           |
---------------------------
```

All tables have a `n:m` relation table to the `references` table. With one query I want to `SELECT` all references and **filter/order** them by author name or keywords etc. So the output I want is something like this:

*User searched by **title***:

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | title   | subtitle    | authors                        | keywords     |
| 1  | Test    | Just a test | Peter Pan, Foo Bar             | boring       |
| 2  | Another | Second      | Peter Pan, Foo Bar, Steve Jobs | boring, lame |
| 3  | Last    | Third       | Peter Pan, Foo Bar, Steve Jobs | boring, lame |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

At this moment I have a very long construct that is not quite working:

```
SELECT r.* , Authors.author AS authors, Keywords.keyword AS keywords
FROM references AS r
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT r.pid AS pid,
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(\' \', CONCAT(p.lastname, \',\'), p.prefix, p.firstname) SEPARATOR \'; \') AS author
    FROM reference AS r
    LEFT JOIN reference_author_mm r2p ON r2p.uid_local = r.uid
    LEFT JOIN author p ON p.uid = r2p.uid_foreign
    GROUP BY r.pid
) Authors ON r.pid = Authors.pid
```

This `LEFT OUTER JOIN` statement exists multiple times for every `n:m` relation to `references`. What would be the easiest way to query these tables. Keep in mind that I need to e.g. `ODER BY` the authors or search through the keywords of a reference.

#### Edit:

The new query I tried:

```
SELECT r.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(\' \', CONCAT(a.lastname, \',\'), a.prefix, a.firstname) SEPARATOR \'; \') AS authors,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(\' \', k.name)) AS keywords,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(\' \', c.name)) AS categories,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(\' \', p.name)) AS publishers
FROM reference AS r
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM reference_author_mm AS rha
        INNER JOIN author AS a ON a.uid = rha.uid_foreign
) AS a ON a.uid_local = r.uid
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM reference_keyword_mm AS rhk
        INNER JOIN keywords AS k ON k.uid = rhk.uid_foreign
) AS k ON k.uid_local = r.uid
```

Comment: Please provide a couple more rows showing the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to make my query as clear as possible according to the table struture you specified in your question (not what I could see on your queries).
You will probably need to change some field/table name.

You can have a look on the query result here : <kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/741a9/3)</kbd>

```
SELECT
    r.id
    ,r.title
    ,r.subtitle
    ,ra.authors
    ,rk.keyworks
FROM
    reference r
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT
            r.id
            ,GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(a.firstname, ' ', a.lastname) ORDER BY CONCAT(a.firstname, ' ', a.lastname) SEPARATOR ', ') as authors
        FROM
            reference r
            LEFT JOIN reference_author_mm r2a
                ON r.id = r2a.uid_local
            LEFT JOIN author a 
                ON a.id = r2a.uid_foreign
        GROUP BY
            r.id) ra
        ON ra.id = r.id
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT
            r.id
            ,GROUP_CONCAT(k.keyword ORDER BY k.keyword SEPARATOR ', ') as keyworks
        FROM
            reference r
            LEFT JOIN reference_keyword_mm r2k
                ON r.id = r2k.uid_local
            LEFT JOIN keyword k
                ON k.id = r2k.uid_foreign
        GROUP BY
            r.id) rk
        ON rk.id = r.id 
ORDER BY
    r.id
```

If you need to order authors name by lastname, just change `CONCAT(a.firstname, ' ', a.lastname)` to `CONCAT(a.lastname, ' ', a.firstname)`

If you have any issue, feel free to update the table structure in my sqlfiddle demo, and leave me a comment that explain what is the issue you are facing and give me examples.

Comment: The example is working well. And the mark-up helps a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe?

```
SELECT r.*,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(\' \', CONCAT(a.lastname, \',\'), a.prefix, a.firstname) SEPARATOR \'; \')) AS author,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(\' \', k.keywords) AS keywords
FROM references AS r
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM references_has_authors AS rha INNER JOIN authors AS a ON a.id = rha.authors_id) AS a ON a.references_id = r.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM references_has_keywords AS rhk INNER JOIN keywords AS k ON k.id = rhk.references_id) AS k ON k.references_id = r.id
GROUP BY r.id;
```

As a last ditch effort, maybe do in application?

Comment: The idea is good! I removed some syntax errors from your answer and tried it but unfortunately the result for the fields `authors` and `keywords` always remain empty. I'll update my question with the new querry.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT dt1.id,dt1.title,dt1.subtitle,dt1.author_name,dt2.keyword_name
  FROM ( SELECT r.id,r.title,r.subtitle,GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(a.firstname,' ',a.lastname)) author_name
       FROM `reference` r
       LEFT JOIN `reference_author_mm` mm ON (r.id = mm.uid_local)
       LEFT JOIN `author` a ON (mm.uid_foreign = a.id)
       GROUP BY 1,2,3
       )dt1
      JOIN( SELECT r.id,r.title,r.subtitle,GROUP_CONCAT(keyword) keyword_name
          FROM reference r
          LEFT JOIN `reference_keyword_mm` km ON (km.uid_local = r.id)
          LEFT JOIN `keywords` k ON (k.id = km.uid_foreign)
          GROUP BY 1,2,3
          )dt2 ON (dt1.id = dt2.id);
```

Comment: @BoltClock : try to post answer for this rather than deleting other users post.

Comment: All keywords that are linked to the current `reference` should be in one field and `,` separated.

Comment: Yeah the above query will linked all the reference with , separated under authors column.
If not post the result you are getting

Comment: I need the same with `keywords`

Comment: I have refined my query. check whether it satifies your question. If so mark it as accepted

Comment: Your query only seems to work for `references` with at least one `author` **AND** one `keyword`. Some entries may also have no `keywords` or `authors`. Also could you explain the `GROUP BY 1,2,3` statement to me, please?

Comment: I have changed my query to work for some possible cases. check it out

Comment: The `LEFT JOIN`s didn't help. I don't know why though. Also `LEFT JOIN`ing the outer join will not return the required result